# How to replace the last HTML list item?

Tags: php, html, string

How do I replace the last `li` element in this string?

Before:

```
$var = 
   '<li>anything<li/>
    <li>anything<li/>
    <li>anything<li/>
    <li>anything<li/>
    <li>anything<li/>';
```

After:

```
$var = 
   '<li>anything<li/>
    <li>anything<li/>
    <li>anything<li/>
    <li>anything<li/>
    <li class="foo">anything<li/>';
```

I tried with `preg_replace()`:

```
preg_replace('<li>', '<li class="foo">', $var);
```

But it isn't the expected output. How do I change the code to get the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just split the string into an array with [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), then I replace the last element and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it again to a string. BTW: You closed the li tags wrong)

```
<?php

    $var = 
        '<li>anything</li>
        <li>anything</li>
        <li>anything</li>
        <li>anything</li>
        <li>anything</li>';

    $var = explode(PHP_EOL, $var);
    $var[count($var)-1] = preg_replace("/<li.*?>(.*?)<\/li>/", "<li class='foo'>$1</li>", $var[count($var)-1]);
    $var = implode(PHP_EOL, $var);

    print_r($var);

?>
```

output:

```
<li>anything</li>
<li>anything</li>
<li>anything</li>
<li>anything</li>
<li class='foo'>anything</li>
```

Comment: I have thought of the solution as well but cannot it be done with `regex`?

Comment: @D4V1D For sure it can be done with a regex you can also use a DOM which would probably be the best if he has more stuff like this to do. But why do you need to make it complicated ?!

Comment: I'm not looking for the complicated solution, just the cleanest one :)

Comment: Also, the OP wanted to have `<li class='foo'>anything</li>`, not `<li class='foo'></li>`. I also assume that `anything` could be whatever word. Would your solution still work?

Comment: @D4V1D Thanks for the notice, missed that in the question, just updated it

Comment: Thank, desired output is but another.. :-(

Comment: @IngDedek What is different to your expect output?! I don't see any difference

Comment: @Rizier123 word "anything". anything == everything, text, number, empty.... I do not know what those before the. Sorry - My English is very bad :-(

Comment: @@Rizier123: Is not. Word "everything" does not change.

Comment: @IngDedek You don't have the word `everything` anywhere!

Comment: @Rizier123 OK, let it go. I ask elsewhere. Thank you.

Comment: @IngDedek What?! Can you please tell me where you have the word `everything` in your code?! I don't see where you would have it! Also can you please post the expected output again here in the comments

Comment: @ Rizier123: 1) big problem === my english! 2) Output <li class='foo'>text</li> or <li class='foo'>number</li> or <li class='foo'>number and text</li> etc..

Comment: @IngDedek You can change the text what you want to replace in this line: `$var[count($var)-1] = "<li class='foo'>anything</li>";` as you want it !?

Comment: @IngDedek updated my answer, I think I now know what you mean. Now the code takes the text from the input and just adds the class. Just copy my entire code again and it should work for you

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = 
   "<li>anything<li/>
    <li>anything<li/>
    <li>anything<li/>
    <li>anything<li/>
    <li>anything<li/>";
   $pos=strrpos($var,"<li>");
echo $final=substr_replace($var, '<li class="foo">anything<li/>',$pos);
```

Comment: word anything == text, number, empty, everything.... I do not know in advance what will be there.

Comment: If anything will change, you can do something like: `$replace = substr($var, $pos + 4); $replace = substr($replace, 0, strlen($replace) - 5);` , and instead of `echo $final=substr_replace($var, '<li class="foo">anything<li/>',$pos);` do `echo $final=substr_replace($var, $replace,$pos);`.  In general strpos and substr functions will be more performant that explode/implode or regex