# Is there a way to add another list element at the end of the HTML list?

Tags: php, html-lists

For example, in my test.html:

```
...
<div id="content">
...
        <ul>
          <li>url0</li>
          <li>url1</li>
          ...
          <li>url32</li>
        <ul>
    ...
</div>
```

I want to add another list element ( `<li>url33</li>` ) at the end of the list from my add.php file.

I saw a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368618/how-to-replace-the-last-html-list-item), where a user was replacing the last list element. My thinking is that I would need to just add to the list length somehow then add to that length position... But I could be totally off in how I understand HTML lists (arrays?).

Comment: Do you have some code to show ? Is it a general problem or specific to a file ? Do you have access to it in order to modify it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pure JavaScript solution

```
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var ul = content.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
ul.innerHTML += '<li>url33</li>';
```

or

```
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var ul = content.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.innerHTML = 'url33';
ul.appendChild(li);
```

### jQuery solution

```
$("#content ul").append('<li>url33</li>');
```

### MooTools solution

```
var ul = $$('#content ul')[0];
ul.innerHTML += '<li>url33</li>';
```

### YUI3 solution

```
YUI().use('node', function (Y) {
  var ul = Y.one('#content ul');
  ul.insert('<li>url33</li>');
});
```

### Dojo solution

```
require([
  'dojo/query',
  'dojo/dom-construct'
], function (query, domConstruct) {
  var content = query('#content ul')[0];
  domConstruct.place('<li>url33</li>', content);
});
```

### ReactJS solution

```
<script type="text/jsx">
    /** @jsx React.DOM */
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    var ul = content.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    React.render(
        <li>url33</l1>,
        ul
    );
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/jsx">
    /** @jsx React.DOM */
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    var ul = content.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    React.render(
        React.DOM.li(null, 'url33'),
        ul
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can add element on end of the list

```
$("#content ul").append('<li>url33</li>');
```

Comment: adding an `<li>` to a div won't exactly add it to the list.